# Is there a good website or resource comparing how all exchanges are structured under the hood?

Tags: exchanges, trading, buy-bitcoins

So one of the issues I am running into is that there are competing definitions for things like: **exchange**, **broker**, **trading platform**, **exchange platform**, **centralized**, **decentralized**, **P2P trading**, etc. And also the websites often don't come out and say exactly how the operation is structured.

Regardless of what words you use to describe them, there is a difference between how things like Coinbase vs. Binance vs. Uniswap vs. eToro vs. LocalBitcoins are owned, organized, and operated. Is there a good resource that explains the differences in unambiguous language between all the services you can use to trade Bitcoin?

Comment: I would expect most of these to be considered confidential information.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I've seen one. These links list resources and exchanges:

https://bitcoin.org/en/resources

https://bitcoin.org/en/exchanges

It might be worth looking at crypto venture capital companies to see if they have any market overviews.